# Xamarin de visual studio me tira este error y me saca de la aplicacion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

eso es para la aplicacion en telefonos android fuera de la app ya que los que te proporciona digitalmente funcionan bien ya he probado en 10 marcas diferentes y es igual en todas, ya sean una conbinacion como con los samsung y xiaomi y en telefonos con un sistema operativo android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.companyname.borandiga/md598ea9a8c3764669c06b649b95d1fe5c6.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class 

Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
at 



android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1620)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6698)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run

(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data

```
/app/com.companyname.borandiga-K6HXP9heFJxc5zMbLdWTDQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.borandiga-K6HXP9heFJxc5zMbLdWTDQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.companyname.borandiga-K6HXP9heFJxc5zMbLdWTDQ==/base.apk!

/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:610)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)


at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at `md598ea9a8c3764669c06b649b95d1fe5c6.LoginActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
at md598ea9a8c3764669c06b649b95d1fe5c6.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:29)`at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7040)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
at  `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2809)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)`at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1620)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6698) `at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)`
```